# Creating videos that can interact with users in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video in a website that I'm working on. I have managed to put a button on top of the video.

What I want to do now is that after video reaches a specific time, it stops automatically and the button shows up, and when the user clicks the button, the video resumes and the button hides.

I'll paste the code below:

```html
<div id="video-box">
  <video id="video" class="video">
    <source src="media/theory_of_operation.mp4" autoplay />
  </video>
  <div class="playpause">
    <button id="videobtn" onclick="vidplay()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">N G S</button>
  </div>
</div>

JAVASCRIPT - 

var video = document.getElementById("video");
 video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
  if(this.currentTime >= 15) {
   this.pause();
   $('#videobtn').show();
  }else{
   this.play();
   $('#videobtn').hide();
  }
 });
 function vidplay() {
       var button = document.getElementById("videobtn");
       if (video.paused) {
          video.play();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your element listen on the timeupdate event:

EDIT:

Now the listener will still record events when you resume playing (by clicking on the button), causing the video to stop automatically the next second since this.currentTime is still superior to 15.
To prevent this behaviour, you could either remove the listener when clicking the button if you don't need it anymore, or set a boolean variable which the listener is going to check to know if whether or not it has to stop the video.

```
video = document.getElementById("video");
stoppable = true;

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 15 && stoppable) {
        this.pause();
        $('#videobtn').show();
    }
});

function vidplay() {
   if (video.paused) {
      stoppable = false;
      video.play();
      $('#videobtn').hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: its working but after i click on the button which appears after the video is paused, it pauses again instantly. What do i do to solve that?
i tried `if(this.currentTime == 5 * 60) but it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you edit your question by adding the code of your vidplay() function ?

Comment: sure. have a look.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: That worked like a miracle, thanks :) Cheers!
Can i let you know if i need help with something else?

Comment: If you take the time to write clear and precise questions, anyone will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in you javascript code.
This created a function that runs every 1 second and checks the video current time.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){ 
    var currTime = vid.currentTime;
    if (currTime == 50)
    {
        // show button
        $("#vidplay").show();

        // stop this interval
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
 }, 1000);
```